# How can I completely remove an item out of a ListView/XML in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, listview

- **The application**
  The goal of the app itself is to manage the being of physical keys that really exist. You can change values, add keys (which works just fine) & should be able to remove keys (in case of wrongly adding a key etc.).
  The keys are items of a ListView and when adding/editing a key the ListView is saved into a XML-File, which I am doing with the XmlSerializer. When starting the app it also loads the saved XML into the ListView, which also works fine.
- **The problem**
  When I try to directly delete/remove an item out of the ListView (and afterwards save & load the XMl again) I am getting an Error for my Loading Method, since the XML now has **multiple root elements**. When I check the XML-File itself, I can see that indeed the key is *moved out of the actual root element* and **has its own closing tag**, which causes the error & makes the app fail to load.
  It looks like this:

```
</ArrayOfSchluessel><Id>12</Id>
    <Schluesselausgefolgt />
    <Raum>0</Raum>
    <ObenUnten />
    <Widmung />
    <Verwahrer />
    <Buntbart xsi:nil="true" />
    <Tosisch xsi:nil="true" />
    <ZahnungZylindrisch xsi:nil="true" />
    <Wende xsi:nil="true" />
    <Doppelbart xsi:nil="true" />
    <Andere xsi:nil="true" />
    <Gesamtbestand>0</Gesamtbestand>
    <Alarmschluessel>0</Alarmschluessel>
    <Reserveschluesselkasten>0</Reserveschluesselkasten>
    <HakenNummer>0</HakenNummer>
    <Seite>0</Seite>
    <Ausgabegrund>0</Ausgabegrund>
  </Schluessel>
</ArrayOfSchluessel>
```

(Where the Key with Id 12 is the one being removed). My Delete Method is as following:

```
public void SchluesselLoeschen(Schluessel ZuLoeschenderSchluessel)
        {

            SchluesselListeItemSource.Remove(ZuLoeschenderSchluessel);
            SchluesselListe.ItemsSource = SchluesselListeItemSource;
            

            SchluesselSpeichernXML();
            SchluesselLadenXML();

            MessageBox.Show("Schlüssel erfolgreich gelöscht!", "Erfolg");
        }
```

It pretty much looks the same as the working Add method, except the *.Remove()* Instead of *.Add()*. As you can see, I am using a workaround, since I am working with ItemSource (to load/save), which worked fine for adding and is confusing me in this case of removing. The object **SchluesselListeItemSource** is a *List* and works as a *temporary placeholder/saver* for the actual ItemSource of the ListView **SchluesselListe**. The object **ZuLoeschenderSchluessel** is the selected key of the ListView which is being parsed from another window (the Edit-Window). My saving Method is the following:

```
public void SchluesselSpeichernXML()
        {

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Schluessel>));

            using (FileStream stream = File.OpenWrite(DateiPfadHC))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stream, SchluesselListe.ItemsSource);
            }
        }
```

and the Loading Method:

```
public void SchluesselLoeschen(Schluessel ZuLoeschenderSchluessel)
        {

            SchluesselListeItemSource.Remove(ZuLoeschenderSchluessel);
            SchluesselListe.ItemsSource = SchluesselListeItemSource;
            

            SchluesselSpeichernXML();
            SchluesselLadenXML();

            MessageBox.Show("Schlüssel erfolgreich gelöscht!", "Erfolg");
        }
```

The Schluessel object itself (which is/are the objects inside of the List/ListView) is my model of a key. It just contains all the different values that a key should be able to hold (with getters & setters) and a public constructor (that creates a key with an id only), which I use for adding new Keys (to edit after).

I tried using several different types of Lists or saving objects, but since it is somewhat removing the Item, just not quite, and the Adding-Method is working I can not think of a solution & was not able to find something on the web, that really is similair to this, since I am working so close to the XML-File, which is a big factor of this app.

Comment: did you try to delete old file. Or try to overwrite old file ?

Comment: @Ugur Deleting the whole file doesnt really change anything. After I add new keys & try to delete the same thing happens. I do not know how exactly the XmlSerializer works, but I believed that it just overwrites the file already. Am I wrong?

Comment: There might be other problems. You need to share your key class "Schluessel". And how do you get your "ZuLoeschenderSchluessel" in delete method.

Comment: And you may need to change root class to like a container class, which keeps keys etc.

Comment: @Ugur Just give me a moment, I will add the code & explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you write data to the existing file and afterwords there is a mix of new and old data.

So replace the `File.OpenWrite(DateiPfadHC))` with `new FileStream(DateiPfadHC, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)`.

Because of `File.OpenWrite` does create a stream with `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.

**FileMode.Create:**

> Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. **If the
> file already exists, it will be overwritten**. This requires Write
> permission. FileMode.Create is equivalent to requesting that if the
> file does not exist, use CreateNew; otherwise, use Truncate. If the
> file already exists but is a hidden file, an
> UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.

**FileMode.OpenOrCreate:**

> Specifies that the operating system should open a file if it exists;
> otherwise, a new file should be created. If the file is opened with
> FileAccess.Read, Read permission is required. If the file access is
> FileAccess.Write, Write permission is required. If the file is opened
> with FileAccess.ReadWrite, both Read and Write permissions are
> required.

Comment: You are welcome! Btw the Lord and Savior is JC. ;)

Comment: Ofc, I was just using it as a phrase, bc I found it suitable ;-)